# How do I translate the output of map.Envelope.BottomLeft to a LatLon?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mapsui

I'm creating an app with MapsUI and Xamarin.Forms.

"BottomLeft" is of type "Point" and has values:
X: -20037508.342789
Y: -20037508.342789

I'm not really sure what these values even are.  I've read they might be pixels, but that doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me.  TopRight is the same values negated.  I can't seem to get anything useful out of this information.

MyMapControl.Viewport.ScreenToWorld(map.Envelope.BottomLeft) just gives me a point with the Y coordinate negated (so it's positive now).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://mapsui.com/documentation/projections.html#the-most-common-scenario

Comment: @Jason Thanks, this helped.  Seeing the juxtaposition of the two coordinate formats/projections helped me understand what I was looking at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.  I was trying to grab the "Envelope" of MapsUI's MapView.Map

What I really needed was MapView.Viewport.Extent.

I had a second problem where I was trying to grab this information before the map was loaded.  That's why I always got X: -20037508.342789 Y: -20037508.342789 for bottom left.
This notation is in EPSG:3857 format and these coordinates equate to the south pole.  I wanted traditional "lat/lng" which is EPSG:4326.

So first I waited til the map was loaded to grab the coordinates, then I found this formula for conversion from EPSG:3857 to EPSG:4326 and implemented it in C#:

```
    private double[] Convert3857To4326(double X, double Y)
    {
        double lng = X * 180 / 20037508.34;

        double lat = Y / (20037508.34 / 180);
        lat = ((Math.Atan(Math.Pow(Math.E, ((Math.PI / 180) * lat))))/(Math.PI / 360)) - 90;

        return new double[] { lng, lat };
    }
```

If you need to go the other way, here's the inverse:

```
    private double[] Convert4326To3857(double lat, double lng)
    {
        double x = lng * 20037508.34 / 180;

        double y = Math.Log(Math.Tan((90 + lat) * Math.PI / 360)) / (Math.PI / 180);
        y = y * 20037508.34 / 180;

        return new double[] { x, y };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what [projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection) your map is using. Mapsui's samples often use the openstreetmap background map. This map is in a projection called [SphericalMercator](http://epsg.io/3857). In this case you can use the Mapsui class SphericalMercator with the ToLonLat and FromLonLat methods.

[Here](https://github.com/Mapsui/Mapsui/blob/master/Samples/Mapsui.Samples.Common/Maps/CenterOnLocationSample.cs#L27) is some sample code.

[Here](http://mapsui.com/documentation/projections.html) some more documentation on projections in Mapsui.